# How to deal with double word names in a list when trying to match them with user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need a little help on my project. Using the list provided, I need the user to enter a sentence with the name of at least one fruit, and then I need to match the fruits entered to the list and essentially read it back to the user. The output doesn't matter right now. I can get it to match as many fruits as are entered, unless the fruit name contains 2 words, such as "Passion Fruit" or "Mandarin Oranges". [Remember I am a 1st semester student just starting to learn so keep it super basic.]
Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!
Please see my work so far below.

```
fruits = [
'Apricots',
'Asian Pears',
'Avocados',
'Bananas',
'Blackberries',
'Blueberries',
'Boysenberries',
'Cactus Pear',
'Cantaloupe',
'Cherries',
'Coconut',
'Cranberries',
'Figs',
'Gooseberries',
'Grapefruit',
'Grapes',
'Honeydew Melon',
'Kiwifruit',
'Limes',
'Longan',
'Loquat',
'Lychee',
'Madarins',
'Malanga',
'Mandarin Oranges',
'Mangos',
'Mulberries',
'Nectarines',
'Oranges','Papayas',
'Passion Fruit',
'Peaches',
'Pears',
'Persimmons',
'Pineapple',
'Plums',
'Pomegranate',
'Prunes',
'Quince',
'Raisins',
'Raspberries',
'Rhubarb',
'Strawberries',
'Tangelo',
'Tangerines',
'Tomato',
'Ugli Fruit',
'Watermelon'
]

x=[]


input_sentence=input("Please type a sentence containing at least 1 fruit name :").title().split()
for fruit in fruits:
    new_fruit=fruit.replace(" ","_")
    x.append(new_fruit)

y=input_sentence
    
glue="_"
z=glue.join(y)

    
def intersect (x,y):
    return list(set(x) & set(z))
print (intersect(x,z))
```

Comment: `[v for v in fruits if v.lower() in 'I would like 10 Ugli Fruit and 3 Cactus Pear'.lower()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the in keyword as below:

```
fruits = [ 'Apricots', 'Asian Pears', 'Avocados', 'Bananas',
           'Blackberries', 'Blueberries', 'Boysenberries', 'Cactus Pear',
           'Cantaloupe', 'Cherries', 'Coconut', 'Cranberries', 'Figs',
           'Gooseberries', 'Grapefruit', 'Grapes', 'Honeydew Melon',
           'Kiwifruit', 'Limes', 'Longan', 'Loquat', 'Lychee', 'Madarins',
           'Malanga', 'Mandarin Oranges', 'Mangos', 'Mulberries',
           'Nectarines', 'Oranges','Papayas', 'Passion Fruit', 'Peaches',
           'Pears', 'Persimmons', 'Pineapple', 'Plums', 'Pomegranate',
           'Prunes', 'Quince', 'Raisins', 'Raspberries', 'Rhubarb',
           'Strawberries', 'Tangelo', 'Tangerines', 'Tomato', 'Ugli Fruit',
           'Watermelon' ]

input_sentence=input("Please type a sentence with at least one fruit name :")
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in input_sentence:
        print(f'Found this fruit: {fruit}')
```

You may also want to consider making the user input case-insensitive by converting both the user input and the list items to upper case for the purpose of comparison:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit.upper() in input_sentence.upper():
        print(f'Found this fruit: {fruit}')
```

Comment: Good tip! But the problem is I'm already using that more or less and if it hits something like "Passion Fruit" it doesn't recognize it at all and with "Mandarin Orange" it only sees "Orange" and ignores Mandarin.

Comment: @AnthonyFranklin it does recognize passion fruit and mandarin orange. Copy and paste this code and try it. When you enter your user input, make sure you capitalized the compound words exactly as it is done in your list. The code simply looks at each string item in the fruits list and determines whether that item is in the user input regardless of how many words are in the item. You could have ‘slightly ripe bananas’ in the fruits clusters and it would recognize it in the user input without any problems. There is no need the join the words like you were trying to do.

Comment: YES! That's awesome! You were right, sorry about that. Now just need to figure out how to work that into my code. Thank you so much pakpe!

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = [
'Apricots',
'Asian Pears',
'Avocados',
'Bananas',
'Blackberries',
'Blueberries',
'Boysenberries',
'Cactus Pear',
'Cantaloupe',
'Cherries',
'Coconut',
'Cranberries',
'Figs',
'Gooseberries',
'Grapefruit',
'Grapes',
'Honeydew Melon',
'Kiwifruit',
'Limes',
'Longan',
'Loquat',
'Lychee',
'Madarins',
'Malanga',
'Mandarin Oranges',
'Mangos',
'Mulberries',
'Nectarines',
'Oranges','Papayas',
'Passion Fruit',
'Peaches',
'Pears',
'Persimmons',
'Pineapple',
'Plums',
'Pomegranate',
'Prunes',
'Quince',
'Raisins',
'Raspberries',
'Rhubarb',
'Strawberries',
'Tangelo',
'Tangerines',
'Tomato',
'Ugli Fruit',
'Watermelon'
]

input = "I like to eat Asian Pears"  # user Input sentence

for fruit in fruits:  # iterate over fruits
    if str.__contains__(input, fruit):   # use string method contains to check if fruit is in user input
        print(fruit)   # if find print
```

Iterate over fruit list to check if fruit is in user input Sentence will do the work.